# express js - socket io connection

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

Unable to integrate socket io and express js .
Below is my html code.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
hello world.
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.5.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
   var socket = io();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my app.js of express js.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('client connected.');
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

Problem : Unable to connect socket io with express.
Below is the image which shows errors in developer console, when i run the app.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your same code, removing `var routes = ...` and `var users = ...`

and adding at the end `server.listen(3000);` instead of the exports it just works for me.

https://dripr.io/file/NkWBbbHR

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me

```
const express  = require('express')
const socketIo = require('socket.io')
const http = require('http')

const app = express()

const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = socketIo(server)

io.on('connection',(socket)=>{
    console.log('client connected: ',socket.id)
    socket.on('disconnect',(reason)=>{
        console.log(reason)
    })
})

server.listen(5000, err=> {
    if(err) console.log(err)
    console.log('Server running on Port ', PORT)
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const http = require("http");
const port = 4000;
const { joinUser, removeUser, findUser } = require('./users');

const app = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200, headers);
    res.end("API");
    return;
});

const server = app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server Started..');
});

const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "*",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    }
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('socket connected..', socket.id);
    socket.on('chat', (data) => {  
        io.sockets.emit('send data', {
            id: socket.id
        });
    io.sockets.emit('chat', { data: data, id: socket.id });
});

socket.on('typing', (data) => {
    socket.broadcast.emit('typing', data);
});

socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    const user = removeUser(socket.id);
    console.log(user);
    if (user) {
        console.log(user.username + ' has left');
    }
    console.log("disconnected");
    });
});
```

Comment: This is server.js code for enable the server. First you have to connect your node server to run the socket without using express js. And then call socket api for communication from server to client.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add information. Also you seem to have missed a closing `}` in `io.on('connection')...`